# How to access Web Speech API controls with Processing

Tags: processing, speech, google-speech-api

I am trying to access microphone button at this [page](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html) by using Processing. I got the source so I managed to launch my own page in order to do possible changes.

Is this possible? If it is not, is there any workaround to manipulate controls of this page?

Comment: We can help you if you provide more information and details, what you tried, code, and so on

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be much more complicated than you're currently thinking.

If all you want to do is interact with the controls **on that page**, then you might look into the `Robot` class. This restricts you to deploying as a Java application (not as JavaScript), but it allows you to do things like move and click the mouse. That might be the way to go if you just want to interact with that page.

However, what you probably want is to use the underlying **API** being used by that page. If this is the case, you don't actually care about that webpage- that's just another **client** that's calling the API on the **server**. You need to create your own client that calls that same API.

To do that, you're going to need to write JavaScript that calls the API. [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API?hl=en) is a guide on how to use the API.

It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions. It's much easier to answer specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. So I highly recommend reading the link I gave you (google is also your friend), trying to write some code, and posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a specific question if you get stuck. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. You gave good info let me dig in and try to apply on my project.